# How to access JSON data returned from a jQuery .post?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery .post call that needs to process the returned data, and despite the numerous other similar posts, I cannot seem to get the syntax quite right.

Here is my jquery call:

```
$.post("fetchAlleles.php", {mndx: mndx, sndx: sndx},
function(result) {
  $('#allele1').text(result[0]);
  $('#allele2').text(result[1]);
}, "json");
```

And here is the php code that is called:

```
    $mndx = $_POST['mndx'];
    $sndx = $_POST['sndx'];

    $dbconnect = pg_pconnect("host=".$hostname." user=".$dbuser." dbname=".$dbname);    
    if (!$dbconnect)    {
        showerror(0,"Failed to connect to database",'fetchAlleles',16,"username=".$dbuser.", dbname=".$dbname);
        exit;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT allele1, allele2 FROM geno.genotypes WHERE markers_id=".$mndx." AND gsamples_id=".$sndx;

    $fetchresult = pg_exec($dbconnect, $sql);
    if ($fetchresult) {
        $arr = pg_fetch_array($fetchresult, 0, PGSQL_NUM);
    } else {
        echo "(25) Failed to retrieve results.<BR>SQL: ".$sql."</br>";
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Now, I know the php is working correctly, as I can see in Firebug that it returns the desired data. I just don't see how to access it using the success function. I want to assigned the return data to the value of the two elements id allele1 and allele2.

I know I'm close, but haven't been able to find quite the right example, or decipher the jquery documentation. Any help will be much appreciated!

--rixter

EDIT 1: Here's the answer:

$("#allele1").get(0).value = result[0];
$("#allele2").get(0).value = result[1];

from Simanchal Pattanaik (found in another question)

answered my question...thanks Simanchal!

Comment: Any chance the #allele1 elements don't support the text function? Sorry, but my javascript is a bit rusty. But you may want to check those string concatenations when building the select query. Isn't that prone to SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

The Json object in javascript will match whatever Json the php returned.

If you want to see the structure, watch the fiddler traffic and click the JSON inspector tab.